# Array initialization in C#: Why does one fail at run time, and the other at compile time?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Consider the following two programs.  The first program fails at compile time with a compiler error:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<int> bar = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; //CS0622
    }
}
```

> Can only use array initializer expressions to assign to array types. Try using a new expression instead.

**This I fully understand.**  Of course, the remedy is to use the `new[] {...}` array initializer syntax, and the program will compile and run properly.

Now consider a second program, only slightly different:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Foo {
    public IList<int> Bar { get; set; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Foo f = new Foo { Bar = { 0, 1, 2, 3 } }; //Fails at run time
    }
}
```

This program compiles.  And what's more, the run-time error generated is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is interesting to me.  Why would the second program even compile?  I even tried making `Bar` an instance variable instead of a property, thinking that might have something to do with the odd behavior.  It does not.  As in the first example, using the `new[] {...}` array initializer syntax causes the program to run properly with no errors.

It would seem to me that the second program should not compile.  Here's the question.  **Why does it?**  What is it I'm failing to grasp here?

(Compiler: Visual Studio 2012, Framework: .NET 4.5.1)

Comment: Thanks.  I'd searched for that, but wasn't able to find the answer.  Figured I had a 75% chance of someone else finding this.

Comment: I was pretty surprised to find this already answered as well, but it actually popped up in the "Related" section of this question. Stack Overflow may have just become sentient.

Comment: "On June 3, 2014, Stack Overflow became self-aware.  In da confusion dey try to pool da plug"